# Why does TeamCity server stop short time after it starts

Tags: teamcity

I use TeamCity with bundled Tomcat server. I start TeamCity server using `runAll.sh start` command. The server starts and I can access its web interface. However, within a minute or two the server stops. I checked `teamcity-server.log` but it doesn't contain any information about server stopping. How can I debug it?